# Restrict ajax API use to iOS / Android application

Tags: javascript, android, ios, ajax, cordova

Given the scenario that you have valuable data being served from an API (mysite.com/api/OooOOooData), how can access to it be restricted to the iOS / Android app that it is intended for? It is paramount that the data be associated with the proper advertising via the apps. If the API can be used apart from that, the data is being given out for free with no reward from advertising, or other developers could be using it and actually stealing the profits.

If this were a web-only app, it would be no issue to restrict the usage to my own site. Because this is possible and important when dealing with the web, I am inclined to think that there is something in place to deal with this issue with other technologies. My project is using web technology with Cordova. There's no user system, so authentication isn't an option.

The only measure I know I could implement is to arbitrarily include a key in my code and send it with all ajax requests, then have the server require that key. Since the code is in a private repo, only users with jailbroken phones should be able to see that code. That's an obviously weak solution and too much of a risk.

Is there a standard and secure approach to this?

Comment: public restricted API will usually give the application's developer a private key to include in the requests.

Comment: I don't think there's a 100% secure approach. There will always be a way for someone to reverse engineer the client app and/or spoof their requests. Perhaps you can do a combination of 1) make it difficult to reverse engineer and 2) monitor requests to detect abuse. But the right solution might be to rethink your reward system.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a php code as following:

```
<?php
$agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
if(strpos($agent,'IPhone') !== FALSE){
// The client is an IPhone
}else{
// The client is not an IPhone
}
?>
```

And no, there is not a secure way to do this. (As far as i know)

Comment: This doesn't guarantee the client is the intended app. Plus, user agents are easily spoofed.

Comment: Right, this could just as soon be an iPhone app that is a knock-off of ours, or anything else if they faked the header.

Answer (score 0):

On the whole there is no 100% secure way to do it as far as i know, most of the authorization/authentication mechanisms are based on trust. Having said that i have couple of suggestions

1. Have a private key/public key kind of validation on the server. store the public key on the device and private key on server and then validate the requests by sending the key as a part of the POST request.This obviously assumes that the certificate doesn't get stolen or shared across.
2. You can generate a client id and client secret for each user who is registered to use your service, and let this be used as a part of the authentication instead. Again this assumes that the developer who is registering the data doesnt share his identity with other folks.

Comment: Good suggestions in general but they don't guarantee the client is the intended app. And since the OP is using Cordova, they can be reverse engineered easily.